# How to create a video from numpy array without looping?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I want to make a video from array which shape is (70000, 640, 480, 3).
the first axis is the number of photos which I want to collect them into a video without using loops to append each photo .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 4-dimensional empty numpy array first, and then set the values later on

```
import numpy as np
videos = np.zeros(shape=(70000, 640, 480, 3))

videos[60000][300][200][1] = 300  # set values later when needed
```